# Making a date field reactive in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a `datepicker` component from `ngx-bootstrap` a custom date-field, so that I can globalize some functionality and configs. But I can't seem to be able to catch the value of the `Date` object in the date input field.

My `date-field.ts` (I'm re-using some setup from a text-field. So bear with me if you see some remnants of the text field component. But I'm sure that my main problem is that my component doesn't know it's a date field)

```
  import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

  @Component({
    selector: 'date-field',
    templateUrl: './date-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./date-field.component.scss'],
    providers:[
      {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
        multi: true,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateFieldComponent),
      }
    ]
  })
  
  export class DateFieldComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

    public dateField = new FormControl("")
    private onChange: (name: string) => void;
    private onTouched: () => void

    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() required: boolean;

    datepickerConfig = {
      dateInputFormat: 'ddd, MMMM Do YYYY', 
      isAnimated: true, 
      adaptivePosition: true, 
      returnFocusToInput: true, 
      containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue'
    } 

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }


    writeValue(obj: any): void {
      const date = Date
      this.dateField.setValue(new Date());
      console.log(date);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
      this.onChange = fn;
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
      this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
      if (isDisabled) {
        this.dateField.disable();
      } else {
        this.dateField.enable();
      }
    }

    doInput() {
      this.onChange(this.dateField.value)    
    }

    doBlur() {
      this.onTouched();
    }

  }
```

The template HTML:

```
  <label
    *ngIf="label"
    for="{{name}}"
    class="col-auto col-form-label {{required ? 'required' : '' }}">
    {{label}}
  </label>
  <div class="col-expand relative">
    <input 
      type="text"
      class="form-control date-field"
      #dp="bsDatepicker"
      [formControl]="dateField"
      (input)="doInput()"
      (blur)="doBlur()"
      ngModel
      bsDatepicker
      [bsConfig]="datepickerConfig"
      required="{{required}}">  
  </div>
```

Using it in parent forms like this:

```
 <date-field
     name="dateChartered"
     label="Date local union chartered"
     formControlName="dateChartered"
     required="true">
 </date-field>

 <p><strong>Date chartered is:</strong> {{dateChartered}}</p>
```

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Will it be due to having `ngModel` on a reactive form? I know I came accross this problem before as it already have the `formControlName`. So how it access it was through `thisform.control.value` instead. And may I know in the
`writeValue()` function how can you log the value of `date` when it hasn't been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in your parent component you're correctly initializing `FormGroup` in controller and using it correctly in template, you have two main errors in your component.

First, as [Belle Zaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9508627/belle-zaid) says, you should remove `ngModel` from you custom datepicker's `<input>`.

Second, you are binding `doInput()` to `(input)`, but it will fire only if you type in your input field, same for `(change)`. You should bind to `(bsValueChange)` that's an output event exposed by `BsDatepicker` and it's safer, unless you plan to update value on user's input.

The resulting template will look like this:

```html
<label *ngIf="label"
       for="my-custom-datepicker"
       class="col-auto col-form-label {{required ? 'required' : '' }}">

  {{label}}

</label>


<div class="col-expand relative">
  <input id="my-custom-datepicker"
         type="text"
         class="form-control date-field"
         required="{{required}}"
         bsDatepicker
         [formControl]="dateField"
         [bsConfig]="datepickerConfig"
         (blur)="doBlur()"
         (bsValueChange)="doInput()">  
</div>
```

Once done the two changes you will notice an error in your console:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was
> checked. Previous value for 'ng-pristine': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more
> at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

This is due to the fact that calling `this.dateField.setValue(obj)` in `writeValue` will also trigger `(bsValueChange)` and, thus, `doInput()`. To overcome this issue, you can edit your code like the following:

```
private componentInit = false;

// ...

doInput() {
  if (!this.componentInit) {
    this.componentInit = true;
    return;
  }

  this.onChange(this.dateField.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked! It's tough being a ReactJS working as the only AngularJS dev in my proj lol